# How to release the locally alloc init NSMutableArray and return its reference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have one function like this

```
    -(NSMutableArray *)getData
    {
       NSMutableArray *tempArr=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      // perform some operation on tempArr
      return tempArr;
    }
```

In above example i created new object for nsmutablearray and need to return its refernce.
Now everything is working fine however when i run it with instruments (leaks) it shows 100 % memory leak at  "NSMutableArray *tempArr=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];" this line .

what can be solution for this ,please do write to this thread

Thnx in advce

Comment: in this case uses a autorelease

Comment: thnx for your quick reply but one thing i dont understand is when will it remove the value from that memory location

Comment: If you were using ARC, that would be all you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to release it on return, like so

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)getData
    {
       NSMutableArray *tempArr=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      // perform some operation on tempArr
      return [tempArr autorelease];
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually do this:

```
return [tempArr autorelease];
```

Consider switching to ARC.

Answer (score 2):

For such cases you should use autorelease like this...

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)getData
    {
       NSMutableArray *tempArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
      // perform some operation on tempArr
      return tempArr;
    }
```

hoping this helps.